# Static Files in google app engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

i am building a project in which i have to retrieve text content of a file,i read this article https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles .in this article i can store file in the war/ directory and access it.but it is publicly accessible any one can access this file my file contain some sensitive data where to store this file and how to access it?? please guideline!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to designate static file as described here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely store statis files and process them as required in your application. Please keep your files into a folder that is not directly accessible by others.

I suggest the following:

1. Keep the files inside of `/WEB-INF/myfiles` or some folder like that inside of the `/WEB-INF` folder.
2. Use the File APIs to read the content of the files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok i got. make a folder with weired name that only i know but is it not possible to store a file that is only accessible by app only not publicly accessible.if some one know absolute path of file then he can get that file .

Comment: one second please clarify if i put a file in war directory then it is public and when i store it in war/WEB-INF/myfiles then it is private right ??

Comment: Yes. It is not directly accessible.